# perl http request, how to truncate output

Tags: perl, http, get, request, truncate

I am trying to user perl to read a text file online, using a call like this:

```
$output = $ua->request($req)->as_string;
```

The problem is that output has a lot of garbage in it that I don't want, e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: 
etc...
```

Is there a way to truncate the output so I get only the contents of the file?

Comment: Did you try looking at the `HTTP::Response` docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are simply getting the response object from `LWP::UserAgent` and just dumping it as a string. If you want to get just the content:

```
# Get the response
$response = $ua->request($req);
# Get the content portion of the response
$output = $response->content;
```

It's all there in black and white: https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request